# The ideal in this definition has to be homogeneous

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm using two different sources to study algebraic curves (Fulton is one of them) and I'm facing with two different definitions of projective algebraic sets apparently contrasting each other:

**Source 1**

[image: Source 1]

**Source 2**

[image: Source 2]

[image]

So in the source 2 the author says that the definition of projective algebraic sets is well-defined just if $I$ is an homogeneous ideal, then he is simply saying that the definition in the source 1 is not well-defined, I'm confused.

I need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: May I ask what book Source 2 comes from? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fulton seems to have taken a bit of a shortcut here. The point is that for any, not necessarily graded, ideal $I$ (or its generating set $S$), the algebraic set $V(I)$ is determined by the homogeneous pieces of $I$ (or forms in $S$).

Thus, to match with the next, more detailed definition, he could say that $V(I)$ is the algebraic set defined by the graded ideal generated by all the homogeneous terms in $I$. This is essentially what he means when he writes $V(I) = V(\{F_j^{(i)}\})$.

For example, a polynomial $x+x^2$ on $\mathbb P^1$ determines $V(x+x^2) = V(x,x^2) = V(x)$. One might initially think that $[-1: y]$ lies in $V(x+x^2)$ for any $y$, but $[-1:y] = [1:-y]$, and $1+1^2\neq 0$. Thus, $V(x+x^2) = V(x) = \{[0:1]\}$. (Notice that in the affine case we'd get $V(x+x^2) = \{-1,0\}$.)

Comment: Thank you for you explanation and with your example everything becomes clearer.

Comment: Just a little question about $V(x+x^2)$ in the affine case. Why $(0,1)$ is not in $V(x+x^2)$?

Comment: Dear @user42912, I should have said: considering $x+x^2$ as a polynomial on $\mathbb A^1$.